# OOP design pattern

Tags: oop, design-patterns

This question has been bothering me for quite a while:

I have a `Room` class, and lets say I want to add a `Ball` entity.

`Ball` should have `x` and `y` coordinates that represents a location in this room.

So here is the question:

What class should hold the coordinates?

1) Each `Ball` for it self.

2) The `Room` will hold the coordinates of every `Ball`.

I know that it's probably doesn't matter much, but what is preferred choice or what is more popular?

**EDIT**:

What I'm actually worried about, is that object can change it's content however it like, so having it limited by some third party would solve it. But I guess it's only valid for applications with multiple users, not my case.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I'll go with the first options then.
Since the ball also may have color, so having them all in one place will be smart.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When it comes to object design, one of my starting mantras is "*the object knows everything about itself*". Imagine the Ball having to ask the Room - *where am I?* I would start with the Ball holding it's coordinates. This way the Room only has to know about itself and a collection of Ball objects. Conversely the Ball knows everything about itself. Any details the Room may need about Ball coordinates can be gathered by iterating the the collection. When you get around to adding other objects to your room, you'll impact your design a lot less as well.

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates should go with the class `Ball`. For example: you could have one, two, three or more (or a dynamic number of) `Ball`s instances in the `Room`and each has its own coordinates.

The exception would be if you need to do some heavy processing on coordinates of balls and you prefer to have those stored as vectors. In that case, the choice would be to put those vectors as members of `Room`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it highly depends how you look at the problem. Ball is an Object and each Object have a co-ordinates in real world. In the other hand, Room is a container of objects and could contain position of objects it contains.

What I normally do, is to look which way my program would be simpler to develop, because I am too lazy :D . That said, I prefer to inherit Ball from PositionableObject and store co-ordinates in that class. So, after any inheritance of this parent class, all of my object would have co-ordinates or locations ...

Comment: The fact that *Room* is a container does not means that it contains (directly) the coordinates of *Ball*, just that it contains references towards the contained objects (and that it destroys those objects with itself).

Comment: Still it depends how you look at the problem. For example, for robocup simulations server, a server stores location of each player and informs objects of their positions. You as a person, could not say what is your exact position in the room, so an object may have an idea about it's position, but not the exact one ...

Comment: That's rather a Command design pattern: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Code/Design_Patterns#Command

Comment: Still categorizes as Object Oriented Design! See, we may say, it may depends which one changes the position, the object or the container ...

Comment: That's true, but do not forget, that even if the Container is holding the coordinates, it must pass those coordinates to the contained objects, in order to allow those to update their positions. Basically, the Container maintains a cached copy of the coordinates (the later are stored in the properties of the contained objects, even if not in an explicit form, but in their other properties). It is a duplication of data, after all.

Answer (score 0):

If the Room class has a Ball object, and the Ball object is the location of the Ball within the Room, I would have to say the Ball object should have the X Y coordinates.

Say a Room doesn't have a Ball; now you are storing the X Y coordinates for the ball within the Room object even though there is no ball (bad design).

Additional if the room had more than one ball. There could be different coordinates for each ball.

Comment: "Now you are storing the X Y coordinates for the ball within the Room object even though there is no ball" - You missed me there.

Comment: I meant that if you were to store the x y coordinates in the Room and the Room had no Ball, then you have a property for X Y coordinates of a Ball in the Room object. Think, is it possible for a Room to exist without a Ball? Also couldn't a Ball be at an X Y coordinate that's not in a Room?

Answer (score 0):

In tha case you are describing, propbably having the coordinates as a property of the ball is easy and gives to ... the point ;-)

But in more general terms the question may be surprising: imagine many balls and many rooms, each having more coordinate systems. Ball coordinates make sense only after choosing a coordinate system, so coordinates are, in fact, a *link* between a ball and a coordinate system.

If you are interested in describing the position of the ball respect to all the systems, this cannot be done with a linear composition, but requires a collection of balls, a collection of rooms and a collection of coordinates, where each room contains a collection of records each containing a ball reference and a coordinate reference for that ball in that context.
The ball itself can then have a collection or record each being a room reference and a coordinate reference.

You than need a space manager that is friend of rooms and balls and that takes care of updating all the coordinate if a room or a ball are moved and maintain collections reciprocal consistence.

But this goes far beyond your initial purpose. I just point this out to let you think about a potential wider abstraction.